# Instagram API Angularjs Login without redirect

Tags: angularjs, api, authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to make a form *username/password* in my angularjs app. And when user fills this form and submits it I want to log him in to instagram and receive his instagram id, access_token etc. I saw the website in js where they do this way, and I would like to know how do they do this. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

If Instagram support [resource owner password credentials](http://www.rfcreader.com/#rfc6749_line368) as  their Oauth authorization type, you easily accomplish that.

Or you can refer to [oauth.io](https://oauth.io/providers) which provides a mature solution to no-redirection oauth authorization.